# Do inflows influence bond prices and/or yields

Tags: bonds

In the absence of selling, additional purchases of an equity drive the price up.

What if any sort of effect does purchasing do to the price and/or yield of a bond (irrespective of interest rate effects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in any market, purchases will bias the price process to be higher than without buying. Much of market microstructure research shows that for theoretical reasons and confirms it with empirical work.

Fixed income ranges from much more liquid than most equities (US Treasuries) to far less liquid than equities (municipal bonds, very small corporate bonds, emerging market debt). A thorough overview is [Bessembinder, Spatt, and Venkataraman (2020)](https://www.sec.gov/spotlight/fixed-income-advisory-committee/survey-of-microstructure-of-fixed-income-market.pdf); you might also find this [2016 BIS CGFS paper](https://www.bis.org/publ/cgfs55.pdf) informative. Finally, [Ottonello (2019)](https://www.sec.gov/spotlight/fixed-income-advisory-committee/fimsac-110419-background-ottonello.pdf) shows that inflows to bond funds tend to push prices higher (and thus yields lower).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something empirical, reading through the [Investopedia Guide to Fixed Income](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fixedincome.asp), but not finding an answer. I will have a look at the resources you've mentioned.

Comment: A lot of those are empirical and they reference more empirical work. However, you will not likely find an estimated price impact model... because that gets too close to "secret sauce."